# Getting a total from inputboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently working in a school project for a renting tool. I'm working on the billing page and I need to get a total from a few inputs. Below is how it looks like and I need to get the total using jQuery.

[image]

Comment: please share your HTML and JS code.

Comment: can you add your markup instead of picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   var sum=0;$('.add').blur(function(e) {
   var n=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
sum=sum+n;
$('.sum').val(sum);
});});


<table><tr>
<td><input type="number" name="number1" class="add" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="number2" class="add"  /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="number3" class="add"  /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="number4" class="add"  /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="number4" class="sum"  /></td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
$('.total').val(function(){

  var v = 0;

  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:not(:disabled)').each(function(){
     v += parseInt(this.value, 10);
  });

  return v;

});
```

<sub>Guessing you have all inputs in a table's tr element.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

**HTML**

```
<div id="textFields">
    <span>
       <input type="text" class="inpt" name="inpt1" value="0">
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="text" class="inpt" name="inpt2" value="0" />
   </span>
    <span>
       <input type="text" class="inpt" name="inpt3" value="0" />
   </span>
</div>
<div class="total">
   <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="sumation" />
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
$("body").on("keyup",".inpt",function(){
  var total=0;
  $.each($('.inpt'),function(k,v){
         total=total+parseInt($(v).val());
});
$(".sumation").val(total);

});
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un6kf1rc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

So many possibilities..

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $('selektor').append('<input class="input" type="text" name="name' + i + '">')
}
$('selektor').append('<input id="total" class="total" type="text" name="total">')
$('.input').on('keyup', function () {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.input').each(function () {
    if (isNaN($(this).val())) return;
    sum += $(this).val() - 0;
  })
  $('#total').val(sum);
})
```